# Clojure split lines with all empty lines kept

Tags: clojure

I'd like to split a string by lines, keeping all empty lines, including trailing ones. The basic functions I found seem to trim these:

```
user=> (require 'clojure.string)
nil
user=> (clojure.string/split-lines "a\n\nb\n")
["a" "" "b"]
user=> (clojure.string/split "a\n\nb\n" #"\n")
["a" "" "b"]
```

I'd like the last empty line(s) kept, as in this python example:

```
>>> 'a\n\nb\n'.split('\n')
['a', '', 'b', '']
```

What is the right way to obtain that in clojure ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
user=> (clojure.string/split "a\n\nb\n" #"\n" -1)
```

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split

Comment: Wow it works, thanks. Are we supposed to be able to see that just from the doc ? I  (now) see -1 mentioned in one of the examples, but have trouble relating it to the "number of splits".